# How to make work Indicator-Chars app?

Tags: python, indicator, clipboard

I downloaded [Indicator-Char](https://askubuntu.com/a/52281/62483) and unzipped the files. I added the characters there I wanted perfectly. When I run the python script it loads the daemon and I can see this characters. But the problem is that when I click on them, the app **doesn't copy anything to the clipboard**.

The following code belongs to the **copy function** of the program:

```py
def on_char_click(self, widget, char):
    cb = gtk.Clipboard(selection="PRIMARY")
    cb.set_text(char)
```

Is a syntax problem? There is a problem on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://standards.freedesktop.org/clipboards-spec/clipboards-latest.txt:

> - explicit cut/copy commands should always set both CLIPBOARD and    PRIMARY, even when copying doesn't involve a selection (e.g. a  "copy url" -option which explicitly copies an url without the  url being selected first)

Copy char command could look like this:

```
cb = gtk.Clipboard(selection="PRIMARY")
cb.set_text(char)
cb = gtk.Clipboard(selection="CLIPBOARD")
cb.set_text(char)
```

From the same link:

> Apps that follow these guidelines give users a simple mental model to
>   understand what's going on. PRIMARY is the current selection. Middle
>   button pastes the current selection. CLIPBOARD is just like on
>   Mac/Windows. You don't have to know about PRIMARY if you're a newbie.